# Bus routes in Delhi, India?

Tags: india, buses, new-delhi

When I did a search on Google Maps for how to get from [one destination to another](http://goo.gl/maps/VDl7i) all I saw were walking routes and driving routes. I didn't see any bus routes.

[Transport in Delhi#Buses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_in_Delhi#Buses) mentions [DTC Bus Routes](http://www.onefivenine.com/india/BusRouteStage/bus_Delhi_6759_Routes.htm) but there it looks like I have to look at every route until I find one that passes by the two destinations. And even then it doesn't have the schedule.

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont know where you are from, but I'd suggest you google up some pics or videos on Delhi buses. I wouldn't want them buses to be my ride in rush hour at least : http://i.images.cdn.fotopedia.com/everlasting-i1WCRxZwsyA-ifill_1024x768/Countries_of_the_World/Asia/India/pilgrims_bus.jpg and http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-gqh3TWP-Oek/T4uvt2QmSII/AAAAAAAAA0c/ECsZhgpR7yo/s1600/aptopix-india-transit-2010-5-3-14-47-39.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Delhi Transport Corporation](http://www.delhi.gov.in/wps/wcm/connect/DOIT_DTC/dtc/home) has its own home page where it lists the [schedule for different bus routes](http://www.delhi.gov.in/wps/wcm/connect/66af22004e01eacd841ea4d4f77cccee/Time+Table+of+DTC+Bus+Routes.xls?MOD=AJPERES&lmod=1052413919) *(dead link)* in a downloadable Excel spreadsheet. (Different routes are listed in different "sheets" within the spreadsheet so switch using the tabs at the bottom.) There's [a second spreadsheet for fare stages that lists all stops on a particular route](http://www.delhi.gov.in/wps/wcm/connect/7eed618043fc14debc9abd3b1bcb8004/Fare+Stage+and+Fare+Chart.xlsx?MOD=AJPERES&lmod=-552552806&CACHEID=7eed618043fc14debc9abd3b1bcb8004&Fare%20stage%20&%20%20Fare%20chart) (you need to switch to the "Fare Stage" tab). Perhaps not the most intuitive way but at least you have the information in some form. Usually, people at bus stops will be happy to help you out with information on what bus route to take (if they speak English, that is).

Another pertinent point is that given Delhi's traffic, it's highly unlikely that the bus schedule will be helpful. [YMMV](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ymmv), don't expect the buses to turn up or reach their destination on time.

Comment: The schedule for different bus routes link gives me this error: Error 404: Error reported: 404

Comment: I too recieved the same error.

Comment: Yeah the link id dead. The main site does have a schedule link, but it redirects to the homepage. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this app, to see the routes: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsimplify.delhidtcbus

Comment: Could you give some more information on it? It looks popular on the app store, but some information would be useful.